# Electron: force specific resolution for content and scale to fit window

Tags: html, electron, resize, scale

I have a strange requirement with an electron application where I need to be able to force the document to render at a specific resolution and then stretch or squash it to fit the window. For example, I need to specify that the content size is 1920x1080 but then need to squash that down to an actual window size of say 1280x960.

I have tried to implement this in the DOM by setting a fixed body size and scaling this down to fit the window but this has a knock on effect on other transforms and animations which expect the non-scaled version. I need a solution which works outside the DOM so the document behaves as if it actually is running in a 1920x1080 window but then the rendered result is scaled up or down to fit the actual size of the window.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to set the native resolution of the window but maybe you can use the HTML `viewport` meta header. or use `BrowserWindow setAspectRatio`. or use `webFrame.setZoomFactor(2)` from electron api